# A server and a client both run on a PC. Can the client connect to the server using the IP of the PC?

Tags: c++, networking

I'm new to network programing, so this is something that has perplexed me for days.

I wrote 2 apps: one is a server, one is a client.

What i want them to do is this: When i supply the client with an IP address, the client would connect to the server on the machine with the supplied IP.

I tested it out by opening both the server and the client on my PC, typing in the loop back address (127.0.0.1). The client connected to the server fine (and i could even send text message from each other).

So i tried further. I googled my IP (which was 113.20.98.124) and then fed it to my client. I expected the client would connect to the server as well, but that didn't happen. The client terminated and said that connection timed out (WSAETIMEDOUT 10060).

What i want to ask is: why can't i use my IP to tell the client to connect to my server? Is that even a thing?

Here are my codes of the server and the client (in case i did something wrong):

(I coded using VS2017 on Windows)

Client:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <string>


//The port which will be used to connect to server
#define PORT "7777"


std::string getIPAddress()
{
    std::string out;
    std::cout << "IP/Domain to connect to: ";
    std::cin >> out;
    std::cin.ignore();
    return out;
}

//Print out error code and exit the program in case something goes wrong
void failure_exit(std::string message, int exitVal)
{
    std::cerr << message
        << " Error code: " << WSAGetLastError() << " \n";
    WSACleanup();
    std::cin.get();
    exit(exitVal);
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1, 0), &wsaData) != 0)
        failure_exit("WSAStartup failed!", 1);


    addrinfo hints;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; //AF_INET or AF_INET6 are totally fine
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; //TCP connection


    //Get the IP from user
    std::string IPconnect = getIPAddress();


    //A pointer to a linked list of juicy results we can use 
    addrinfo *result(nullptr);

    //Prepare the addrinfo for a connecting socket
    if (getaddrinfo(IPconnect.c_str(), PORT, &hints, &result) != 0)
        failure_exit("getaddrinfo failed!", 2);


/*PREPARING A SOCKET*/
    SOCKET sockfd;
    //A pointer to one of the addrinfos from result, which is a usable one
    //'chosen' will also be used in connect() call
    addrinfo *chosen(result);
    //Run through the results got from getaddrinfo and pick the first usable addrinfo
    for (; chosen != nullptr; chosen = chosen->ai_next)
    {
        //see if sockfd is legit to use
        if ((sockfd = socket(chosen->ai_family, chosen->ai_socktype, chosen->ai_protocol)) != -1)
            break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    //Socket preparation failed
    if (sockfd<=0)
        failure_exit("Socket preparation failed!", 3);


/*CONNECT!*/
    std::cout << "Connecting... 20 seconds until timed out.\n";

    if (connect(sockfd, chosen->ai_addr, chosen->ai_addrlen) != 0)
        failure_exit("Failed to connect!", 4);

    std::cout << "Connected!\n";

    WSACleanup();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Server:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <string>


//The port which this server will be using 
//to listen to incoming connections
#define PORT "7777"

//Limits how many pending connections
//can be queued up
#define BACKLOG 10


void failure_exit(std::string message, int exitVal)
{
    std::cerr << message
        << " Error code: " << WSAGetLastError() << " \n";
    WSACleanup();
    std::cin.get();
    exit(exitVal);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1, 0), &wsa) != 0)
        failure_exit("WSAStartup failed!", 1);


    addrinfo hints;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    //IPv4 or IPv6 are both Ok
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    //This addrinfo will be used for binding
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    //TCP connection
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;


    addrinfo *result;
    if (getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &result) != 0)
        failure_exit("getaddrinfo failed!", 3);


//PREPARE A SOCKET
    SOCKET sockfd(0);

    //The usable addrinfo will be pointed to by 'chosen'
    addrinfo *chosen(result);

    //Loop through the results to find a suitable one
    for (; chosen != nullptr; chosen = chosen->ai_next)
    {
        sockfd = socket(chosen->ai_family, chosen->ai_socktype, chosen->ai_protocol);
        //Stop at the first usable
        if (sockfd != -1)
            break;
    }
    freeaddrinfo(result);

    //Check for preparation failure
    if (sockfd <= 0)
        failure_exit("Socket preparation failed!", 4);


    //Bind the socket above to my chosen PORT
    if (bind(sockfd, chosen->ai_addr, chosen->ai_addrlen) == -1)
        failure_exit("Binding failed!", 5);


    //Start listening for incoming connections
    if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1)
        failure_exit("Listening failed!", 6);


    //The new socket to be returned by accept()
    SOCKET newfd;

    sockaddr_storage newConnection;
    socklen_t newlength(sizeof(newConnection));

    std::cout << "Anyone?\n";

    //Accept a pending connection
    if ((newfd = accept(sockfd, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&newConnection), &newlength)) == -1)
        failure_exit("Accepting connection failed!", 7);

    std::cout << "Connection accepted!\n";

    WSACleanup();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Anything i learnt about network programming has been derived from http://beej.us/guide/ .

Comment: "A server and a client both run on a PC. Can the client connect to the server using the IP of the PC?" - Yes. As well as the link local address 127.0.0.1 (IPv4) or ::1 (IPv6).

Comment: If you have no static IP and port forwarding in your router it cannot work. Be happy! Otherwise your system would be open to the world.

Comment: @ArminMontigny So my IP isn't static? How can i figure out if it is? (and i also don't understand the 'port forwarding' part)

Comment: When you found "your IP", you didn't find the IP address of the client or the server, you found the public IP address of your router. Punch "port forwarding" into your favorite search engine.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Port forwarding won't help either unless the router supports hairpin NAT, which is quite unusual to have turned on in consumer-grade equipment.

Comment: @BenVoigt It used to be a few years ago, but over the past five years, it has become the norm. Lack of support for hairpin NAT is now considered a defect and industry standards call for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you Googled your IP, you got your public IP as it is seen by the outside world. If your PC is *directly* connected to your Internet modem, then that IP belongs to your PC. But, if your PC is behind a network router (which is very common nowadays with households having many Internet-connected devices), then that IP belongs to your network router, not to your PC.

Your server app can listen only on local/LAN IPs that have been assigned directly to the PC it is running on. If that PC is running behind a network router, it cannot listen to your router's public IP.

Your server code is binding its listening socket in such a way that it listens on all available IPv4 IPs that are assigned to the PC it is running on. To discover what those IPs actually are, you can use Windows' command line `ipconfig` tool. Or, in your server code, you can use the [`GetAdaptersInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersinfo) or [`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses) APIs.

If your client is running on the same PC/network as the server app, it can connect directly to any local/LAN IP that the server is listening on. But if the client is running on a different network (ie, on another PC over the Internet), it needs to connect to your public IP instead. And in the case where that public IP belongs to a network router, the router needs to be configured to forward inbound connections on a given `<PublicIP>:<PublicPort>` to the server PC's `<LanIP:LanPort>` (ie, forward from `113.20.98.124:777` to something like `192.168.0.1:777`, or whatever IP is actually assigned to the server PC).

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer! So this is what I understand from it: That the 113.20.98.124 is not the IP of my PC, but my network router. I ipconfig-ed and it said my local IP is 192.168.0.105. So i need to somehow, from my client, connect to the router 113... and then forward to my local IP, is that right?

Comment: @RevolNoom if your client and server are running on opposite sides of the router, then yes, you need to go into the router settings and setup a public port that forwards from 113.20.98.124 to 192.168.0.105, then your client can connect to 113.20.98.124. But, if your client and server are running on the same side of the router then you don't need to do this, the client can connect to 192.168.0.105 instead